# How to open Fragment OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to open a new fragment but getting the error:

> cannot resolve getFragmentManager

I tried some solutions but am still getting the error. How do I solve it?

Here is my adapter code where I set the `OnClickListener`:

```
public class RecyclerViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
public ImageLoader mImageLoader;

//List of superHeroes
List<ListOfData> superHeroes;

public RecyclerViewDataAdapter(List<ListOfData> superHeroes, Context context) {
    super();
    //Getting all the superheroes
    this.superHeroes = superHeroes;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ListOfData superHero = superHeroes.get(position);

    mImageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    mImageLoader.get(superHero.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView1, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
    holder.imageView1.setImageUrl(superHero.getImageUrl(), mImageLoader);
    holder.textViewName1.setText(superHero.getName());
    //holder.textViewName2.setText(superHero.getName());
    //holder.textViewRank.setText(String.valueOf(superHero.getRank()));
    //holder.textViewRealName.setText(superHero.getRealName());
    //holder.textViewCreatedBy.setText(superHero.getCreatedBy());
    //holder.textViewFirstAppearance.setText(superHero.getFirstAppearance());

    String powers = "";

   /* for(int i = 0; i<superHero.getPowers().size(); i++){
        powers+= superHero.getPowers().get(i);
    }*/

    //holder.textViewPowers.setText(powers);

    holder.imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public Activity context;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BehindTheLayoutFragment nextFrag= new BehindTheLayoutFragment();
            this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.behind_the_layout_fragment, nextFrag)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();


        }
    });

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return superHeroes.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public NetworkImageView imageView1;
    public TextView textViewName1;
    public TextView textViewName2;
    public TextView textViewRank;
    public TextView textViewRealName;
    public TextView textViewCreatedBy;
    public TextView textViewFirstAppearance;
    public TextView textViewPowers;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView1 = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        textViewName1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_title_one);
        /* textViewRank= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRank);
        textViewRealName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRealName);
        textViewCreatedBy= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCreatedBy);
        textViewFirstAppearance= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFirstAppearance);
        textViewPowers= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPowers);
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you solves this one? Do you need an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

`getFragmentManager` has to be called on an `activity` instance not on `RecyclerViewDataAdapter`.

Use this class either as an inner class in your Activity or use the reference you pass in the RecyclerViewDataAdapter's constructor to get the fragment manager

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RecyclerViewDataAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder>
{

recycleListener mListener;
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
holder.imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public Activity context;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      mListener.onClick();

    }
});


 public interface recycleListener
 {
  void onClick();
 }


}




  public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewDataAdapter.recycleListener
  {

  public void onClick()
  {
 BehindTheLayoutFragment nextFrag= new BehindTheLayoutFragment();
        this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.behind_the_layout_fragment, nextFrag)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();

  }

   }
```

Comment: gettting Null point exception at 


holder.imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public Activity context;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.onClick(); --------> showing NullPointerException

            }
        });

Comment: remove "public Activity context;"line from onClickListener and check

Comment: fristly i was getting error at this line "this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.behind_the_layout_fragment, nextFrag)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();"

then i changed the getFragmentManager to getSupportFragmentManager and the error was gone but i'm getting error null point at mListener

Answer (score 0):

Things to note !!

1.) getFragment manager is called on activity context, whereas getChildFragmentManager is called on fragment context

2.) this refers to the parent class. Inside the adapter class this will refer to the adapter class so you can't do

```
this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.behind_the_layout_fragment, nextFrag)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

Why? As said in point 1. getFragmentManager is called onactivity context. But hey you are already passing the context in your adapter. So simply do

```
context.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.behind_the_layout_fragment, nextFrag)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
```